# pass function with argument to method call

Tags: php, medoo, flightphp

I'm trying to use flight PHP framework for routing and medoo framework for database usage.

```
//connect database
$database = new medoo([
'database_type' => 'sqlite',
'database_file' => 'db.sqlite'
]);
//my function
function database($database){
$database->insert("ppl", [
"fn" => "joe","ln"=>"doe"]);

}
//
Flight::route('/add/', array(database($database)));
```

How to invoke my function with argument from this place:

```
Flight::route('/add/','database')
```

Tried different variants but getting errors.

Comment: Errors you say...

Comment: yes "invalid callback specified" i read about callbacks in php manual , can't get it work yet.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing, edited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *medoo* or *flight*, but you might be able to use an anonymous function with `use`:

```
Flight::route('/add/',
              function() use($database) {
                  $database->insert("ppl", ["fn"=>"joe","ln"=>"doe"])
              });
```

I think you need to re-architect this into an OOP style that will make it much easier and modular, but in a crunch if `$database` is defined in the global scope:

```
function database() {
    $GLOBALS['database']->insert("ppl", ["fn"=>"joe","ln"=>"doe"]);
}

Flight::route('/add/', 'database');
```